# Changing tags from [the-fairly-oddparents] to [the-fairly-odd-parents]

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

Could someone rename [the-fairly-oddparents](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-fairly-oddparents) to [the-fairly-odd-parents](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-fairly-odd-parents) as this is not one singular word...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sort of is, and sort of isn't. [Officially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fairly_OddParents), the show's name is *The Fairly OddParents*, with the two words squished together into a single compound word. This makes more sense than it appears to - it's a play on "fairy godparents", and "godparents" is also just one word.

I believe the tag name is fine as it is.

Comment: See also: "SpongeBob SquarePants" isn't tagged as "sponge-bob-square-pants".